# char data to float/double

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a memory location of 128 bytes. I try to fill the memory with data starting from 1...127.

I need to write a code which get two parameter like offset , data type. Based on the arguments I need to convert the data on the memory to the specific datatype mentioned.

say for example

```
unsigned char *pointer = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 128);
printf("\n\n loading some default values...");
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            pointer[i] = i + 1;
        }

convertTo(3,efloat);
convertTo(100,edword);    

void convertTo(uint8_t offset, enum datatype){

   switch(datatype)
   {
      case efloat:
       //// conversion code here..
       break;

case edword:
       //// conversion code here..
       break;

case eint:
       //// conversion code here..
       break;

   }
}
```

I tried using many methods like atoi, atof, strtod, strtol, etc.., but nothing gives me correct value. Say if I give offset as 2, eint(16-bit) which should take value 2,3 and give 515

Comment: Hint: All of the methods you list are for converting ASCII to binary. (Not necessary 'ASCII', by the way, but 'the native text encoding of your C compiler'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic version of what you want which wraps the type to convert to and the offset into a single struct. While the template code is more complicated, the usage is IMHO, much cleaner. Additionally, the long switch statement has been removed (at the expense of some less readable template code).

```
// Use an alias for the type to convert to (for demonstration purposes)
using NewType = short;

// Struct which wraps both the offset and the type after conversion "neatly"
template <typename ConversionType>
struct Converter {
  // Define a constructor so that the instances of 
  // the converter can be created easily (see main)
  Converter(size_t offset) : Offset(offset) {}

  // This provides access to the type to convert to
  using Type = ConversionType;

  size_t Offset;
};

// Note: The use of the typename keyword here is to let the compiler know that 
// ConverterHelper::Type is a type
template <typename ConverterHelper>
typename ConverterHelper::Type convertTo(char* Array, ConverterHelper ConvHelper) {
  // This converts the bytes in the array to the new type
  typename ConverterHelper::Type* ConvertedVar = 
    reinterpret_cast<typename ConverterHelper::Type*>(Array + ConvHelper.Offset); 

  // Return the value of the reinterpreted bytes
  return *ConvertedVar;
}

int main()
{
  char ExampleArray[8] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};

  // Create a new NewType (short) using bytes 1 and 2 in ExampleArray
  NewType x = convertTo(ExampleArray, Converter<NewType>(1));
}
```

On the machine I used to test this, x had a value of 770, as John suggested it might.

If you remove the alias `NewType` and use the actual type you wish to convert to, the intention of `convertTo` is, again IMHO, very clear.

Here is a live demo [Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b028b088cfad935b). Just change the type alias NewType to see the output for different types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That example code really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try `*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(pointer + offset)`. Of course, what you will get depends on the endianess of your system. 0x02 0x03 might be interpreted as 0x0203 (515) or 0x0302 (770).